# How can I change the text colour of an MUI Text Field?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've never used MUI before (I'm also very new to react) and I can't for the life of me figure out why the line `inputProps={{sx: { color: "CCCCCC" }}}` isn't changing the text colour. The color for the label and search icon work, but not the input text. It just remains black. How can I fix this? here is the full react component:

```
return ( <div className="navbar"><form onSubmit={requestData}><TextField
    fullWidth
    id="fullWidth"
    label="Enter a fragrance name!"
    InputLabelProps={{ sx: { color: "#CCCCCC" }}}
    inputProps={{sx: { color: "CCCCCC" }}}
    InputProps={{endAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="end"><IconButton onClick={requestData}><SearchIcon sx={{color: "#CCCCCC"}}/></IconButton></InputAdornment>)}}
    onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
    /></form></div>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're using `sx` for styling, which is a custom styling solution provided by the `sx` prop of Material-UI components. To change the text color of the input, you should use the `sx` prop directly on the `TextField` component itself.

```
return (
    <div className="navbar">
        <form onSubmit={requestData}>
            <TextField
                fullWidth
                id="fullWidth"
                label="Enter a fragrance name!"
                InputLabelProps={{ sx: { color: "#CCCCCC" }}}
                InputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                            <IconButton onClick={requestData}>
                                <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "#CCCCCC" }}/>
                            </IconButton>
                        </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    sx: { color: "#CCCCCC" } // Set text color here
                }}
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

I've moved the `sx` prop from `inputProps` to `InputProps` directly, which should correctly style the text color of the input field.